# How to save tmux clipboard buffers permanently so they persist after exiting the shell

Tags: tmux, clipboard

In `tmux`, when yanking some text, it is saved in a list of buffers that we can view/paste from, I have yet to find how to make these persist, once I leave the shell and return, they are now gone.

How would save all of these?

Comment: Not an "automatic" way of doing it that I know of.  As a workaround, you might create a "tmux-save-buffs" shell-script (or function) that would (a) clear the directory where the old buffers were stored, (b) loop the buffer list with `tmux list-buffers -F "#{buffer_name}"`, (c) save each buffer with `tmux save-buffer` off to your chosen buffer directory.  Then reload them with a "tmux-load-buffs" script/function that loops the contents of that directory and `tmux load-buffer` for each file.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds that sounds good to me, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! If you were to include an example of this, I'd happily accept it as the answer. If not then at least I know where I'm going with it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Script to save all clipboard buffers to `tmux-buffers` directory:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/tmux-buffers
tmux list-buffers -F "#{buffer_name}" | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
   tmux save-buffer -b "$line" ~/tmux-buffers/"$line"
done
```

You can then run the following script each time you start `tmux` to load the buffers:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ls -v ~/tmux-buffers | while read line || [[ -n $line ]];
do
   tmux load-buffer ~/tmux-buffers/"$line"
done
```